# Retornar um comando sql em uma function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível retornar um comando sql em uma function para executar como um subselect.

Por exemplo:

```
Select 
*, 
produtos = (nome_da_function())
from
Usuario
```

Pois do jeito que eu fiz eu só consegui retornar como uma string dentro de uma coluna.

A function que eu criei é a seguinte:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RetonarSubselect()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
begin
  declare @subselect varchar(100)
  SET @subselect = (select * from Produto)

  return @subselect 
end
```

Comment: Você diz uma user-defined function do próprio SQL? Não que eu saiba, só como string mesmo.

Comment: Com SQL dinâmico deve ser possível. Se colocares aqui a definição da função talvez possa ajudar.

Comment: Você pode retornar `TABLE` (nesse caso a query que compõe o subselect é executada antes do retorno).

Comment: Nesse caso não me atenderia vou ter que pensar em outra solução para isso.

Comment: Aff! Só agora que vi que a pergunta é de 2015! Mas aqui ela apareceu como recente...

Answer (score 1):

O você precisa utiliza a função `sp_execute_sql` dentro da sua função, nela você poderá passar uma função como `string`, e montar dinamicamente sua `query` como uma string para ser executada

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM AdventureWorksPDW2012.dbo.DimEmployee 
 WHERE EmployeeKey = @level', N'@level tinyint', @level = 109;
```

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo que postou, seria como criar uma subtabela dentro de cada linha da tabela principal. Me parece que isto não é possível no SQL Server. Do jeito que construiu o código principal, o resultado da subconsulta terá que retornar uma única expressão.

Se não houver o limite de número de linhas, crie uma função do tipo *inline valued-table*. Ou seja, o retorno da função passa a ser uma tabela. No comando SELECT principal, acione a função na cláusula FROM, através de junção com a tabela. Se necessário, pode utilizar APPLY, quando para cada linha da tabela Usuário a função será acionada uma vez.

```
-- código #1  
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RetonarSubselect()  
  returns table as  
return SELECT lista_de_colunas  
         from Produto  
go
```

Com JOIN, podemos ter:

```
-- código #2
SELECT U.lista_de_colunas, SS.lista_de_colunas
      from Usuário as U
           left join dbo.RetonarSubselect() as SS on U.coluna = SS.coluna;
```

Com APPLY, podemos ter:

```
-- código #3
SELECT U.lista_de_colunas, SS.lista_de_colunas
  from Usuário as U
       cross apply dbo.RetonarSubselect(parâmetros) as SS;
```

onde geralmente é passado parâmetro para a função, quase sempre coluna(s) de alguma tabela que faça parte da cláusula FROM.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma `procedure` que retorne uma tabela, chamar a `procedure` fazer um `insert` em uma tabela temporária e depois usar essa tabela nas consultas. Pelo que vi você quer por o resultado de um select em uma coluna de outro select, isso seria algo voltado mais para POO, onde você poderia adicionar uma lista, mas no SQL não é possível fazer isso.

Veja se o exemplo abaixo ajuda.

```
create proc [dbo].[CallProc]
as
begin
    select * from Usuarios 
end

 DECLARE @tabela table
    (
         Idusuario int,
         Nome varchar(100),
         idate int
    )

    insert into @tabela
    exec CallProc


    Select 
    *, 
    from Usuario U
    join @tabela T
    on T.Idusuario = U.Idusuario
```